# Django ManifestStaticFilesStorage and imports within javascript files

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

The Django 3.2 [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage) adds a hash value to javascript files called from within a template and this is working as expected. However, some javascript files import from other javascript files and those imported filenames are not translated to a hashed value.  The ManifestStaticFilesStorage documentation indicates that this is done for for CSS files when it finds the import rule and url() statement but is silent on how to do it for javascript.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

As an example, this line in the html template:

```
<script src="{% static 'myapp/js/myjavascript.js' %}" type="module"></script>
```

is rendered like this in the browser (works as expected):

```
<script src="/static/myapp/js/myjavascript.12345abc.js" type="module"></script>
```

But within the myjavascript.js file, this line is left untouched, meaning that the browser could still have a cached version of the imported javascript file and use that instead of an updated version.

```
import {func1, func2, func3} from './javascript_helper_lib.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a slightly different approach.  Rather than using `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`, I am using `StaticFilesStorage` and changing the location of the static files directory during the code deploy.

Before code deploy I create a file called `/path/to/static_dir_location`. The contents of this file are just the path to the actual static files directory such as the app name and release number like `myapp_12345`.  The static dir location is then appended to the `STATIC_URL` variable in `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

with open('/path/to/static_dir_location','r') as file:
    staticdir = file.read().replace('\n', '')

STATIC_URL                  = '/static/{}/'.format(staticdir)
```

This approach forces the browser to reload all static files without the need to inspect and change the contents of any of the files.  Obviously, this can cause longer page load times the first time a user visits the site after the static files are updated so it may not be the best approach for every application.